# Homebrew doesn't work on snow leopard

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

I have a fresh installation of OsX 10.6.8
Yesterday I installed XCode 3.x and then homebrew.

```
brew doctor << was ok
brew update << updated ok
brew install python << gave an error similar to this one:


==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4 --mandir=/usr/local/Ce
checking for gcc... llvm-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/readline-lGgV/readline-6.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

I thought was a problem due to my old XCode, so I uninstalled it and then loaded GCC-10.6.pkg but the error was the same.

I thought that also osx-gcc could be outdate so I managed to find a XCode 4.2 and I installed it, but the error doesn't change

I found out that there is no "Command Line Tools for Xcode" for osX 10.6.8 so now I'm out of options.
There is a newer version of XCode (4.3.2) that is compatible with 10.6.8 but I wasn't able to get it, and sincerely, now I don't think that that could be the problem.

So, now, I'm out of options.
I can't upgrade to Lion, because my laptop doesn't support it.
The sad thing is that yesterday I decided to format my hd and reinstall OsX just to have a new, fresh, clean installation of homebrew!!!!!

Please.....help!!!!

Comment: The problem wasn't the XCode/gcc installation, but something is wrong with readline install. Infact I build it manually and linked into homebrew and then I was able to install python2.7 correctly from brew.              So I solved my issue with this command:  ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4 --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/share/man --infodir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/share/info --enable-multibyte   && make && make install && brew link readline